# How to set a formular to a range of columns in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following excel sheet.
[image: The sheet.]

In this excel sheet, I would like to get the total amount per invoice. The total amount is the sum of sale- sum of refund.For cell B4, I have the following formular which is working perfect.

```
=SUMIFS(D16:D42,B16:B42,"="&A4,C16:C42,"Sale")+SUMIFS(D16:D42,B16:B42,"="&A4,C16:C42,"Refund")
```

Problem is, I want to getthe sum for cells B5-B13. In such a case, Each will be using a cell of A. I tried dragging the Fill handle but all columns in the formula are changed for every new cell in column B. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try using `D$16:D$42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, you are having values change when dragging the fill handle and you do not want that.

I would suggest looking into absolute references as they will not change no matter how where the formula is copied to.

Below image is an example of what I am talking about:

[image]

*This image is from:http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/15.2*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=SUMIFS(D$16:D$42,B$16:B$42,"="&A4,C$16:C$42,"Sale")-SUMIFS(D$16:D$42,B$16:B$42,"="&A4,C$16:C$42,"Refund")

Notice the minus sign (-) after the first sumif as this is crucial since you need to subtract the refund from sale to arrive at the total sale.

Copy the above mentioned formula in B4 to B13 cells.

Hope this helps...